# Trouble inserting in Python (None vs. empty list)

Tags: python, insert, nonetype

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Google's Python class.

E. Given two lists sorted in increasing order, create and return a merged list of all the elements in sorted order. You may modify the passed in lists. Ideally, the solution should work in "linear" time, making a single pass of both lists.

I'm using the following Scheme approach (I wish I had car, cdr and cons!).

```
def helper(list1, list2, result):
  if list1 == None:
    return result + list2
  elif list2 == None:
    return result + list1
  elif list1[0] < list2[0]:
    return helper(list1[1:], list2, result.insert(0, list1[0]))
  else:
    return helper(list1, list2[1:], result.insert(0, list2[0]))

def linear_merge(list1, list2):
  helper(list1, list2, [])
```

The error I get is, I can't seem to insert an element into result when result is []:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

But that works fine in the console:

```
>>> b = []
[]
>>> b.insert(0, 4)
>>> b
[4]
```

I'm brand new to Python, so I have two questions:

1. What am I missing about None vs. [], and how do I get this code to work?
2. If Python wasn't meant for a Scheme/Lisp approach, what's the "Python way" of solving this?  This is less important to me, since I can just check the solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, you almost always want to compare against `None` with `is`, not `==`. But that's not your problem here.

Comment: Hint: `list.insert` modifies the list in-place, and returns `None`. So you probably don't want to pass it as a parameter for a function.

Comment: Also, note that, while this does make a single pass through the lists, it doesn't work in linear time—deleting and inserting on the left end of a list is O(N) in the list size.

Comment: P.S., if you want `car`, `cdr`, and `cons` for Python lists, that's pretty easy: `def car(xs): return xs[0]`, `def cdr(xs): return xs[1:]`, `def cons(x, xs): return [x] + xs`. But again, `cdr` and `cons` will be linear time. If you really want to use Scheme algorithms without thinking about them, build an actual `Cons` type (which is very easy) and use that. Or, better, rethink your algorithm to work from the right, or to work in terms of passing a list and a slice object instead of slicing the list, or…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.insert` returns None, not the modified list.

This requires `helper` to be changed to read

```
def helper(list1, list2, result):
  if not list1:
    return result + list2
  elif not list2:
    return result + list1
  elif list1[0] < list2[0]:
    return helper(list1[1:], list2, result + [list1[0]])
  else:
    return helper(list1, list2[1:], result + [list2[0]])
```

Note the changes to the two base cases. `None` and the empty list `[]` are not the same thing. The pythonic way of testing if a list is empty is to treat the list as a Boolean value: empty lists are `False`, all others are `True`.

---

And as the others have noticed before me, you need to explicitly return the return value of `helper` in `linear_merge`.

Comment: I think you need `result + list1[:1]` or `result + [list1[0]]` or something.  Right now you're adding a list to an element of a list.

Comment: Thanks; I forgot to make that change when switching from `insert` to concatenation.

Comment: Now the OP only has to fix the bug in the algorithm.  :^)

Comment: Got it.  The information I was missing was how to turn an element into a list so I can just add them.  Just put it into square brackets!  Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that `[]` and `None` are not equal.

This causes *two* problems for you.

---

First, your test for the recursive base case isn't working. If you're trying to test for a list being empty, there are a number of ways to do it:

```
if not list1:

if list1 == []:

if len(list1) == 0:
```

But comparing it to `None` is not one of those ways.

The first is generally considered the most Pythonic (and explicitly encouraged by the PEP 8 style guide).

---

Second, you're apparently explicitly calling this function with `None` as an argument somewhere in code you haven't shown us. Don't do that. Call it with `[]` when you mean `[]`.

---

And the other problem is that mutable methods like `list.insert` don't return the mutated object, they return `None`. So, instead of this:

```
return helper(list1[1:], list2, result.insert(0, list1[0]))
```

… you need to either do this:

```
result.insert(0, list1[0])
return helper(list1[1:], list2, result)
```

… or use a non-mutating expression instead:

```
return helper(list1[1:], list2, [list1[0]] + result)
```

---

And then, your `linear_merge` doesn't `return` anything, so its value will be `None`. Change it to:

```
return helper(list1, list2, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

`result.insert` does not return a new list; it modifies an existing `result` in place. Thus you wind up passing `None` as the third argument to your nested `helper()` calls, because that's what `result.insert` returns - `None`.

---

Also note:

```
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
    helper(list1, list2, [])
```

Since you don't `return` anything from `linear_merge`, you're always going to get `None` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a Pythonic solution, as well as how to fix your attempt, I'll write you one as a separate answer.

I'd do this by using iterators. At each step, you yielding the lower value and pulling the next one. The same way you'd do it in Haskell.* This actually *is* linear time, and it's lazy as well. Using [`more-itertools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools):

```
def itermerge(i1, i2):
    i1, i2 = iter(i1), more_itertools.peekable(iter(i2))
    for v1 in i1:
        while i2 and i2.peek() < v1:
            yield next(i2)
        yield v1
    yield from i2
```

---

If you need Python 2.x or 3.2 compatibility, just change the `yield from i2` with `for v2 in i2: yield v2`.

---

If it's not clear how this works, here's the most explicit version, to show exactly what's happening at each step:

```
def itermerge(i1, i2):
    i1, i2 = iter(i1), iter(i2)
    sentinel = object()
    v1, v2 = sentinel, sentinel
    while True:
        if v1 is sentinel:
            try:
                v1 = next(i1)
            except StopIteration:
                yield from i2
                return
        if v2 is sentinel:
            try:
                v2 = next(i2)
            except StopIteration:
                yield from i1
                return
        if v1 < v2:
            yield v1
            v1 = sentinel
        else:
            yield v2
            v2 = sentinel
```

---

If you need a function that returns a list, that's easy:

```
def linear_merge(l1, l2):
    return list(itermerge(l1, l2))
```

---

* This is a bit of a joke. While you can write pretty much any of the immutable versions of this algorithm in Haskell, the one that's most like this solution is probably not the one you'd write.